# Video Range Download - out of memory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, video-streaming, ashx

I have a http hander (ashx) that is used to send out a video to be played on a website.

The video files sizes can be anything from 20MB to 200MB but recently I am receiving an out of memory exception when some of the larger videos are played.
The server has plenty of disk space and usually 1.5GB of RAM available.
I do not get the errors when I run it locally so although there seems plenty of memory on the server there is obviously a problem.

I am not sure if the code is just inefficient but as this is an inherited project I am unsure quite how it works or if there is a better way of doing it.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
  private void RangeDownload(string fullpath, HttpContext context)
    {
        long size, start, end, length, fp = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath))
        {

            size = reader.BaseStream.Length;
            start = 0;
            end = size - 1;
            length = size;

            context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "0-" + size);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"]))
            {
                long anotherStart = start;
                long anotherEnd = end;
                string[] arr_split = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"].Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("=") });
                string range = arr_split[1];

                if (range.IndexOf(",") > -1)
                {
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                    throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");

                }

                if (range.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    anotherStart = size - Convert.ToInt64(range.Substring(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    arr_split = range.Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("-") });
                    anotherStart = Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[0]);
                    long temp = 0;
                    anotherEnd = (arr_split.Length > 1 && Int64.TryParse(arr_split[1].ToString(), out temp)) ? Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[1]) : size;
                }
                anotherEnd = (anotherEnd > end) ? end : anotherEnd;
                if (anotherStart > anotherEnd || anotherStart > size - 1 || anotherEnd >= size)
                {

                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                    throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
                }
                start = anotherStart;
                end = anotherEnd;

                length = end - start + 1;
                fp = reader.BaseStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
            }
        }
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");    
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
        context.Response.WriteFile(fullpath, fp, length);
        context.Response.End();

    }
```

The exception I am getting is:

> Exception type: OutOfMemoryException 
>       Exception message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>      at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SendResponseFromFileStream(FileStream f, Int64 offset, Int64 length)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SendResponseFromFile(String name, Int64 offset, Int64 length)
>      at System.Web.HttpFileResponseElement.System.Web.IHttpResponseElement.Send(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>      at System.Web.HttpWriter.Send(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>      at System.Web.HttpResponse.UpdateNativeResponse(Boolean sendHeaders)
>      at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequestNotification(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context, RequestNotificationStatus& status)

I have updated the code to use a file stream rather than a stream reader like so:

```
   using (var reader = new FileStream(fullpath,System.IO.FileMode.Open,
            System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read))
```

As I've seen it suggested this does not open the whole file in one go but it made no difference.

**Is this a server space issue or is this a coding issue?**

Comment: I'm not an IIS expert but I know that memory available to your site is not as easy as how much memory there is in the server. And 1.5 GB isn't really that much. Do you know how many concurrent requests it takes to tip it over? How many other sites are running on the box? Installing something like Ants Profiler might help you identify a solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc1t4kzs(v=vs.110).aspx) the `WriteFile(String, Int64, Int64)` overload you're using may throw exceptions for large files. There's a [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/812406/prb-response-writefile-cannot-download-a-large-file) article referenced with a code sample that shows how to work around the issue. It basically boils down to splitting the file up in smaller chunks and flushing the outputstream after every chunk.

Comment: Isn't this what the range download does already? I may be totally wrong?!

Comment: @Bex, that's not how I read it. I interpreted the start and end values as a range requested from the video (as byte array). Not as a way to chunk the file. But I could be wrong her too of course.